# How to get value of column by row filtering?

Tags: r

I have the following data table in R:

```
threshold   ranking    size
0.70        11         100
0.65        9          102
0.60        12         150
0.55        10         110
```

I need to get the value of `ranking` for the row when `threshold` is equal to 0.60.

```
threshold_val <- 0.60
out <- as.numeric(filter(df, round(df["threshold"],2) == round(threshold_val,2))["ranking"])
```

But `out` is equal to `NA` instead of `12`.

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: I get out equal to 12 from your code

Comment: @akrun: is there anyway, I can share *.rds file?

Comment: I converted to. `data.table` (if is a data.frame, your code. is working for me) andd then changed to `[[` `filter(df, round(df[["threshold"]],2) == round(threshold_val,2))[["ranking"]]#
[1] 12`

Comment: Sure, if you can show the link.

Comment: @akrun: `threshold` is called `cutoff` in this data set.

Comment: @akrun: Did it work for you on my real data set?

Comment: give me a min. thanks

Comment: what is the name. of 'ranking'.  I get column names as `cutoff phish all_in_range  all precision volume_reduction       precision_ auto_close (1895) auto_close_num`

Comment: ´auto_close_num´

Comment: I get `filter(df, round(df[["cutoff"]],2) == round(threshold_val,2))[["auto_close_num"]]#
[1] 46.07`

Comment: @akrun: I still get NA and error message saying that the index is out of range...

Comment: I am using `packageVersion('data.table')#
[1] ‘1.12.8’` on `R 3.6.2` and as it is a rds data, the structure would be the same

Comment: @akrun: The same for me. Do you read the file as `readRDS(...)`?

Comment: Can you also check whether `filter` from dplyr is getting maske with some other `filter` ile. try `dplyr::filter(df, round(df[["cutoff"]],2) == round(threshold_val,2))[["auto_close_num"]]`

Comment: Yes, I used `readRDS`  `df<- readRDS(file.choose())`

Comment: @akrun: Ouh, `dplyr::` helped!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions that have the same name in different packages.  If those packages are loaded, one of them would mask the other function and the behavior can be totally different.  One option is to specify the `packageName::` before the function

```
dplyr::filter(df, round(df[["threshold"]],2) == 
       round(threshold_val,2))[["ranking"]]
```

Also, when we subset a column, better to use `[[` instead of `[` as it can lead to some bugs